# Change scroll behavior to allow fixed elements to be viewed on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fixed div in my page, as you know if the height of the div is higher than the viewport of the browser you end up with a div you cant scroll since is the background that scroll and not the div (fixed to position).

So lets say:

```
<div class="fixed">

</div>
```

---

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

You can check here http://jsfiddle.net/n7b43s8a/1/ if you reduce the preview  page height you see you cant scroll the div.

The bootstrap modal fix this issue, but I dont quite understand how they do it, seems the take away the scroll of the body and add a new spacer background div but is not clear.

Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/RLQhh/750/

You see, even with a very small height you can scroll the div.

How they do it?

Comment: bootstrap modals use relative position. so use position: relative and set the position using top: 0; left:0;

Answer (score 1):

The key is `overflow`. Add `overflow: hidden` to body, and `overflow: auto` to your `.fixed`.

Of course, this assumes that your fixed container is somehow limited in height, as it will by default stretch to its contents height.

See http://jsfiddle.net/456vashr/ for an example

Comment: good point. but, if the height of the fixed element is bigger than the viewport, you have an issue.

Comment: @sanjithedward True. Which is why fixed containers are commonly applied in percentage sizes.

Answer (score 0):

In the Bootstrap example; they used `position:relative` for their fixed div. You need to change your `position:fixed` to `position:relative`.